# Script not loading on Semplice

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a bit of javascript on my Semplice portfolio
http://kevcharlton.co.uk/project/delete-graduates

The script is there to make the logo rotate on scroll. It NEVER works on first load, but always works on page refresh.

One of my colleagues is saying I need to look into adding a tag such as 
    '$( document ).ready()' 
but I'm a real noob and I have no idea how.

The javascript is quite simple.

```
var logo = document.querySelector('.logo img');
logo.style.transformOrigin = 'center center';
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
logo.style.transform = 'rotate('+(window.scrollY*0.3)+'deg)';
});
```

Anyone able to help?

I also can't get it to work on my homepage http://kevcharlton.co.uk - but I think this might be problematic with the scroll hijacking.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the load order, you might need to wait until the DOM has been loaded because at the time of execution your element might not exist yet.

```
// wait until DOM has been loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var logo = document.querySelector('.logo img');
    logo.style.transformOrigin = 'center center';

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        logo.style.transform = 'rotate('+(window.scrollY*0.3)+'deg)';
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to have an effect. The logo doesn't actually appear crisp until I refresh either.

Comment: @KevCharlton The code works on my machine. Perhaps you need to do a hard refresh to clear the cache.

Comment: I've tried that, it still only seems to work when i refresh the page

Comment: @KevCharlton In that case, you will have to be more specific about what the issue is. Are there any error messages showing up in the devtools?